# How to set up email on Amazon EC2

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have domain. I have my website on an Amazon EC2 instance. I have pointed the domain there, so website is accessible with the domain now. all is working fine but I want to set up the email now, I should be able to create email id and manage emails.

Someone suggested Amazon SES to be set up, I did that but then what to do?
Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried searching through Amazons documentation? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/setting-up-ses.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to run your email on EC2.

Amazon SES is for outgoing email only, i.e. it can replace your SMTP server, so for example if your website generates emails, you could use SES to send them out, but its not a full 'email' service in the traditional sense.

For normal email operations, you need to use an email provider such as gmail, outlook, rackspace email etc.

AWS also offers AWS Workmail as an option. I use both Rackspace email and outlook email for various domains that I have hosted on EC2 instances.

If you are accustomed to using a shared hosting service, i.e. discountasp.net where the web hosting and email is all bundled together as a single packaged service for you, you need to think of things differently when you start running and managing your own ec2 server instances. Its upto you to string the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have hosted website on AWS EC2 and Domain name pointed to Instance. I would suggest that you use AWS WorkMail to send Email. This is new service which has been introduced. AWS WorkMail is available on US East (N. Virginia) and EU (Ireland) region. It is easy to configure and you can use your domain name to create email Ids, say info@domainname.com.

After configuration you will have your own console for where you can manage and access all your emails. To access emails AWS have own console similar to webmail.